# Cannot subclass final class with PowerMockRule

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito, eclemma

I'm using JUNIT with Powermockito and EclEmma to test my Code. Now there is a problem. I have to test this Class:

```
public class Main
{
    private static final Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    private static final Marker marker      = MarkerFactory.getMarker("Test");

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(slf4jLogger);
        slf4jLogger.debug(marker, "Hallo");
        slf4jLogger.trace(marker, "Hallo");
        slf4jLogger.info(marker, "Hallo");
        slf4jLogger.warn(marker, "Hallo");
        slf4jLogger.error(marker, "Hallo");
    }

}
```

Here is my Test:

```
@PrepareForTest({ LoggerFactory.class, Main.class })
public class MainTest
{
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule            rule        = new PowerMockRule();

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException    thrown  = ExpectedException.none();

    /**
     * Test static Fields
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testMain() throws Exception
    {
        Logger logger = PowerMockito.mock(Logger.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        PowerMockito.when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(logger);

        Main.main(null);

        Mockito.verify(logger).debug(Mockito.any(Marker.class), Mockito.eq("Hallo"));
        Mockito.verify(logger).trace(Mockito.any(Marker.class), Mockito.eq("Hallo"));
        Mockito.verify(logger).info(Mockito.any(Marker.class), Mockito.eq("Hallo"));
        Mockito.verify(logger).warn(Mockito.any(Marker.class), Mockito.eq("Hallo"));
        Mockito.verify(logger).error(Mockito.any(Marker.class), Mockito.eq("Hallo"));
    }

}
```

But there is the following Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:447)     at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>     at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
>     at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
>     at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:123)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:59)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
>   ...

I don't want to the powermock-module-javaagent. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a static getter method for `slf4jLogger`, then refactor your `main` method to call this new method. You can then stub this method in your tests :

```
PowerMockito.spy(Main.class);
PowerMockito.when(Main.getSlf4jlogger()).thenReturn(logger);
```

(instead of

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
PowerMockito.when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(logger);
```

)